# How to read this floor map scale?

Tags: floor, interior, design, planning

I'm not an interior designer, but I'm going to do the home design myself. I don't know how to read the scale of this floor plan. I'm going to put this into a floor planner website and design, but I don't know what the parameter of 13300 is. If I'm going to draw a plan on the website (they use meters as a parameter), I need to know what to enter.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers on each side of your plan are probably measurements in millimeters. That's the closest relation I could find to the handwritten 1098 square feet.

7 541 mm * 13 300 mm = 
7,541 m * 13,3 m = 
100,295 square meters =
1 079.5 square feet

Comment: Thanks a lot :D Because i'm not designer and my math is weak :/ regret didn't listen to lecturer while high school :P glad you're here ;)

Comment: I went the other way: 1098 sq ft is roughly 25 x 44 feet (I tried other combinations but the ratio looked right) and 25*300 is 7500, 44 * 300 is 13,200 so you can divide the numbers on your sheet by 300 to get feet (not accurate to the inch, but close)